# loading a picture into tkinter

Tags: python, json, image, tkinter

I am trying to show a picture in the pop-up window. But I can't get it to work. I think I did something wrong at `def apiraadplegen(x)`. I access the API and show the name of the pokemon (input = number). I also want a picture with it. How can I correctly show an image?

```
#importception
import requests
import json
import sys
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.messagebox import showinfo
import urllib
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import PIL

#import poke api
api_url = 'http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/'

#api url dingen
def apiraadplegen(x):
    try:
        r = requests.get(x)
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as error:
        print(error)
        sys.exit(1)
    else:
       # Geen probleem =)
       # decoderen zodat python het kan lezen
        json_data = r.json()
        img = Image.open(json_data['sprites']['front_default'])
        img_1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
        bericht = showinfo(title='Informatie', message='Naam: ' + json_data['name'] + '\n' + img_1)
        return bericht




# def klikken op een knop
def klikkenpokemon():
    try:
        pokenaamurl = api_url + 'pokemon/' + invoer1.get()
        return apiraadplegen(pokenaamurl)
    except:
        showinfo(title='Error!', message='Er is iets fout gegaan.')
        sys.exit(1)

#het programma window
root = Tk()
label = Label(master=root,
              text='Welkom op de Pokewiki!',
              background='white',
              foreground='red',
              font=('Times New Roman', '14'),
              width=40,
              height=5)
label.pack()
#invoer pokemon nummer / naam
invoer1 = Entry(master=root)
invoer1.pack(padx=10, pady=10)
#magische resolve knop
pokeknop = Button(master=root, text='Klik hier', command=klikkenpokemon)
pokeknop.pack(pady=20)
```

root.mainloop()

Comment: Do you get error message when you run it in console/termina/cmd.exe/powershell ? Add full error message in question.

Comment: I tired code and see first problem: API gives you json with url to image - not image pixels - so you have to use requests to download it.

Comment: @furas Can't I load an img from an url? Do I need to download it first?

Comment: `Image()` can read only local file. It doesn't work with url - it treats url as local path (for example on Linux you can have local path with `http://` in name).

Comment: you can try to use `r.content` (from requests) in `Image()`. Or you have to read from `requests` to buffer in memory before you use it in `Image()`

Answer (score 2):

1. `Image()` can read only local file so you have to use `requests` to download image (`r.content`).
2. You can download file on disk and use it with `Image()` or you have to create file-like object in memory (with data from requests - `r.content`) and use it with `Image()`. `Image()` will not work directly with data from requests `Image(r.content)`

   ```
   import io

   fp = io.BytesIO(r.content) # <-- file-like object

   image = Image(fp)
   ```
3. There is problem with `PhotoImage` and `garbage-collector`. It remove `PhotoImage` object created in function and assigned to local variable - you have to assign it to global/external variable: 
   http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm

   ie.

   ```
   image = Image(fp)
   photo = PhotoImage(image)

   image.photo = photo # <-- solution
   ```
4. You need `Label` to display image. I created `Label` in main window.

Finally:

```
#importception
import requests
import json
import sys
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.messagebox import showinfo
import urllib
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import PIL

import io # <-- to create file-like object in memory

# --- constants --- (UPPER_CASE)

# import poke api
API_URL = 'http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/'

# --- functions --- (lower_case)

#api url dingen
def apiraadplegen(x):
    try:
        r = requests.get(x)
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as error:
        print(error)
        root.destroy() # <-- close window
        sys.exit(1)

    # Geen probleem =)
    # decoderen zodat python het kan lezen
    json_data = r.json()

    try:
        r = requests.get(json_data['sprites']['front_default'])

    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as error:
        print(error)
        root.destroy() # <-- close window
        sys.exit(1)

    fp = io.BytesIO(r.content)  # <-- create file-like object in memory

    image = Image.open(fp)  # <-- use file-like object in memory
    photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)

    label_image.config(image=photo) # <-- show image in label
    label_image.image=photo # <-- solution for problem with garbage-collector & PhotoImage

    bericht = showinfo(title='Informatie', message='Naam: ' + json_data['name']) # + '\n' + photo) # <-- you can't display image this way

    return bericht

# def klikken op een knop
def klikkenpokemon():
    try:
        pokenaamurl = API_URL + 'pokemon/' + invoer1.get()
        return apiraadplegen(pokenaamurl)
    except Exception as error:
        print(error) # <-- always print error - on screen or in log file
        showinfo(title='Error!', message='Er is iets fout gegaan.')
        root.destroy() # <-- close window
        sys.exit(1)

# --- main ---

#het programma window
root = Tk()

label = Label(master=root,
              text='Welkom op de Pokewiki!',
              background='white',
              foreground='red',
              font=('Times New Roman', '14'),
              width=40,
              height=5)
label.pack()

#invoer pokemon nummer / naam
invoer1 = Entry(master=root)
invoer1.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

#magische resolve knop
pokeknop = Button(master=root, text='Klik hier', command=klikkenpokemon)
pokeknop.pack(pady=20)

label_image = Label(master=root) # <-- place for image
label_image.pack()

invoer1.focus() # <-- set focus on Entry so you can quickly type text

root.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for helping! I finally understand it 100%.